# Create multiple areas via VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to set an outline border format to a number of ranges in Excel.

Something like this works:

```
Union(Range("A1"), Range("B3")).BorderAround(...)
```

But as soon as the Ranges touch, they will merge into a single range, and the borders will be around the entire merged range instead. Using the `Range("A1,A2")` way works, but is limited in the count of areas and won' work.

Is there any way, given two ranges r1, r2, to get them as separate areas in a single range, regardless of if they touch or not?

EDIT:
A bit of clarifiction:

I have perhaps a thousand areas I want to give borders, sometimes touching. I want to get a single range that contains all the (correct areas) and do the operation on that single range. The reasons for this:

1. I can much more cleanly return the range from a function, e.g. `GetRangesThatNeedsBorder()`.
2. Performance reasons for not doing it one area at a time.
3. It feels more correct and intuitive for the user of that function.

I don't want to use the "string method" of unioning ranges, due to constraints in length. A few options I've considered:

- Use Union, but create two separate ranges, in a sort of striped pattern (only works in specific circumstances), and do the call twice.
- Use the string method but split the string at appropriate places.

Edit 2:
Does the right thing:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("B1"), Range("B3"), Range("C1:C3"))
    Call r.BorderAround(2)
End Sub
```

Fails, merges A1:A4:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("B1"), Range("B3"), Range("C1:C3"), Range("A4"))
    Call r.BorderAround(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not doing it `FOR EACH ...`?

Comment: @DirkReichel, I think the issue is that if you do a `For Each Area in Range...` it combine adjacent cells into one area. A `For Each Cell` on the other hand would put borders around every cell.

Comment: Given your comment to my answer, and re-reading your question, my main question is how many range variables are you talking about?

Comment: If I got you right, having A1:A3, B1, B3 and C1:C3 will look like border around B2 and A1:C3... is that correct?

Comment: @DirkReichel I think I see where you're going, but no. This will give 4 areas. The areas are only joined if they can be made into a single rectangular shape.

Comment: This way you want it to be or not? (to join)

Comment: @DirkReichel In your example, Excel does the right thing, the problem arises because Excel chooses to merge ranges as soon as it can.. If you would add A4 as well, A1:A4 would be consider one range instead of A1:A3 and A4. See my (again) updated question for examples.

Comment: You don't want to merge at all... so why not directly doing this for all areas? I need to run some tests... still will take a while (not at home... just by phone) :D

Comment: *"Use the string method but split the string at appropriate places"*. I vote for this option.

Comment: @A.S.H, this is what my answer does,  but it doesn't seem to be acceptable.

Comment: @DougGlancy Not exactly. In my understanding, the quoted idea by the OP is not to call `BorderAround` for each single area separately, but to group their addresses into a large comma-separated string. But then, to overcome the problem of the string's size limit (i.e. 66 comma-separated items I think), he can split the whole string into a few smaller ones. The difference is that in your solution, there is a string for each individual area.

Comment: @A.S.H, that's true, and one could certainly modify mine to split the string at "as-close-to-255-char-chunks." But why? To make it more complicated and error-prone? :-)

Comment: @DougGlancy That's probably right. But the OP clearly doesnt like it for it would be too slow for a range with too many areas (say each area is a cell), because he assumes that the call to  `BorderAround``would be the bottleneck of his routine. I cannot tell whether this assumption is totally true, but it seems reasonable :)

Comment: @A.S.H, maybe there is a speed difference. It would be cool to hear from the OP if it's been tested.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to start with an address in a string like `"A1,A2:A3,B1:B3,C3"`. In that case, this should work:

```
Sub OutlineManyCells()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim RangeAddress As String
Dim RangeAddresses As Variant
Dim i As Long

RangeAddress = "A1,A2:A3,B1:B3,C3"
Set ws = ActiveSheet
RangeAddresses = Split(RangeAddress, ",")
    For i = LBound(RangeAddresses) To UBound(RangeAddresses)
        ws.Range(RangeAddresses(i)).BorderAround LineStyle:=2
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This gets around the issue of A1,A2 and A3, for example being merged into a single area in a For Each Area in Range("A1,A2:A3,B1:B3,C3"), while letting you put borders around groups of contiguous cells.

For a somewhat related blog post of mine, see: http://yoursumbuddy.com/undo-selections-selectracker/

Comment: No, rather the opposite. Range( "A1,A2:A3,B1:B3,C3").BorderAround _does_ work. The problem is that i don't have the ranges in a string format but as separate ranges. I will update my question shortly.

Comment: Looking at your update it confirms what I thought was the stated issue at the beginning, i.e., the limit to a string addresses length. My answer lets you use a longer string. I don't see any way around using a string, due to the issue with Unioned ranges that you describe.

Comment: But having the ranges as ranges, he could use a `ParamArray` and then run the `For Each ...` as mentioned in my comment, or am I wrong?

Comment: @DirkReichel I want to avoid for each for performance reasons (and because it "feels" better with a single range as it works in any other place).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I needed the answer today. Couldn't find any other solution so I created one myself. Below is a code that can create a Range object from an Range-string of any length.

```
Function RangeFromString(iSh As Worksheet, ByVal sLongString As String, Optional lDepth As Long = 1) As Range
    Dim lPos As Long, sName As String
    If Len(sLongString) <= 255 Then
        Set RangeFromString = iSh.Range(sLongString)
    Else
        sName = "RFS_" & lDepth
        lPos = InStrRev(sLongString, ",", 256)
        iSh.Names.Add sName, iSh.Range(Left(sLongString, lPos - 1))
        Set RangeFromString = RangeFromString(iSh, sName & "," & Mid(sLongString, lPos + 1), lDepth + 1)
        iSh.Names(sName).Delete
    End If
End Function
```